# Glassfish 3.1.2 FacesServlet issue

Tags: java, jsf, glassfish

I have an EAR which I deploy to GF 3.1.1 successfully. Now I am trying out GF 3.1.2. My EAR deploys but the Webapp does not come up.

I get the following Exception.

```
21 Jun 2012 16:34:17,285 ERROR com......web.exception.MyExceptionHandler : Serious error happened!  : Error Parsing /login.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 1] Premature end of file.
javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /login.xhtml: Error Traced[line:    1] Premature end of file.
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile(SAXCompiler.java:425)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doMetadataCompile(SAXCompiler.java:408)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.Compiler.metadataCompile(Compiler.java:130)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.createMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:327)
```

I use Mojarra 2.1.6. But I do not include it in the EAR. I also use PrimeFaces 3.2.

As said, all works well on GF 3.1.1.

There are some sparse messages on the web stating the same issue, but no solution.

TIA,
Coen

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the exact problem is but I have had nothing but problems with Glassfish 3.1.2.

When I first downloaded 3.1.2 it worked OK but then I added calls to some 3rd party web services in my application and things went downhill fast. It even started crashing NetBeans. Do you by chance call any web services from your application?

The most stable / usable configuration I have found is 3.1.1 with Mojarra 2.1.8. My IDE is NetBeans 7.1.2. You can find instructions for installing 2.1.8 on glassfish here:
http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/rlnotes/2.1.8/releasenotes.html

Hope this helps.